# Downloading PDFs in IE8 through SSL via Java causes Browser Window to stay open.

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8

Our application allows the user to download an PDF file.  In an SSL environment, the IE8 opened in the background stays open.

This becomes a problem if the user click on 5 different PDF file links, which means there will be 5 empty IE browsers open.

In a non-SSL environment, the IE8 browser closes.

Relevant code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pdfFile));
String fileData = getStringFromStream(br);
res.setHeader("Expires", ""); 
res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "");
res.setHeader("Pragma", "");
res.setContentType("application/pdf; name=" + sFileName); 
res.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + sFileName);
   //res.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + sFileName);
res.setContentLength(fileData.length());
ServletOutputStream outStream = res.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(fileData.getBytes());
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Comment: I think you need to post more code.

Comment: Is this IE8? IE8 sometimes behaves strangely when specifying Cache-Control, Expires or Pragma headers. Could you try what happens without those headers?

Comment: Hi Eelke, I started without the "specifying Cache-Control, Expires or Pragma headers" behaved same way as with the "specifying Cache-Control, Expires or Pragma headers". Yes it is IE8.